# malloc under linux, implicit limit

Tags: c, linux, malloc

Sorry if the title isn't as descriptive as it should be, the problem is hard to put in a few words. I am trying to find out how much mem i have available by malloc'ing and if that worked, writing to that segment. On certain systems (all linux on x86_64) i see segfaults when writing to the 2049th mib. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    void *addr;
    int megasize = 2100
    /// allocate the memory via mmap same result
    //addr = mmap ((void *) 0, (size_t) megasize << 20, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    //                                                      MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, (int) -1, (off_t) 0);
    addr = malloc(megasize << 20);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
            fprintf (stderr, "alloc of %d megabytes failed %s\n", megasize,
            strerror (errno));
            exit (1);
    };
    printf ("got %d megabytes at %p\n", megasize, addr);
    {
            int i;
            char *p = addr;
            printf("touching the %d Mb memory:\n", megasize);
            for (i = 0; i < megasize; i++) {
                    p[i << 20] = 0;
                    putchar('.');
                    if (i%64==63) // commenting out this line i see that it really is the 2049th mb
                            printf(" #%d\n", i);
                    fflush(stdout);
            };
            putchar('\n');
    };
    /// free the memory
    munmap (addr, (size_t) megasize << 20);
    return 0;
}
```

It segfaults reliably on some systems, whereas on others it works fine. Reading the logs for the systems where it fails tells me it's not the oom killer. There are values for megasize that i can choose which will cause malloc to fail but those are larger.
The segfault occurs reliably for any size bigger than 2gib and smaller than the limit where malloc returns -1 for those systems.

I believe there is a limit i am hitting that isn't observed by malloc and i can't figure out what it is. I tried reading out a few of the limits via getrlimit that seemed relevant like RLIMIT_AS and RLIMIT_DATA but those were way bigger.

This is the relevant part of my valgrindlog

```
==29126== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x39436000, 0xbc836000) (defined)
==29126== Invalid write of size 1
==29126==    at 0x400AAD: main (in /home/max/source/scratch/memorytest)
==29126==  Address 0xffffffffb9436000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Can anybody please give me a clue as to what the problem is?

Comment: With or without overcommit enabled? (Which is the default)

Comment: `sizeof(int)` == 4 I believe, and `int` is signed... trying to go for a value over 2G will result in negative offsets.

Comment: @R.. Technically true, but unlike with multiplications, GCC actually currently supports signed left shifts into the sign bit as an extension, and it's a fairly safe guess that GCC is the compiler that's used. Yes, it's undefined behaviour as far as standard C is concerned, but so is `#include <sys/mman.h>`.

Comment: @Mat: I don't think so. I'm nearly certain I've seen code of the form `for (i=1; i>0; i<<=1);` get compiled to an infinite loop on some versions of GCC.

Comment: (@R..: I didn't argue, you're correct.)

Comment: Oh, I meant to reply to @hvd.

Comment: @R.. I know, I've seen it classified as a bug in the GCC bug tracker :)

Comment: I'd call it a feature. It's reasonable extension behavior for GCC to allow left shifts of negative numbers as long as they don't overflow (i.e. as long as the highest value bit is a 1); this is just extending the definition of `<<n` as *2^n to work for negative values. I don't see any reasonable argument for "supporting" overflow, however. If you really need that behavior, there's the `-fwrapv` option, but it should not be used with code intending to be portable.

Comment: @R.. [Documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation), by the way: "GCC does not use the latitude given in C99 only to treat certain aspects of signed '<<' as undefined, but this is subject to change. " (Hence the "currently" in my earlier comment.) According to the GCC devs, C90 actually requires that `INT_MAX << 1` works, and since I don't have C90, I don't know what C90 says, but the GCC devs have extended that to C99.

Comment: Indeed, C90 seems to define `<<` for signed quantities in terms of representations, and since under this definition `INT_MAX<<1` results in a representation whose value fits in `int`, the text about overflow seems not to apply. See http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.3.7

Comment: On the other hand, I see no text that defines a relative "order" between the sign bit and value bits, so it's unclear that the high value bit would shift into the sign bit per this definition. It's also even unclear that bit 0 would shift into bit 1, and so on...

Comment: @R.. Thanks for that link. Indeed, that is very underspecified. It is only clear what is meant for unsigned types by reading about the multiplication, for I suppose signed types the best that can be done is mapping each bit to one in the corresponding unsigned type, which places the sign bit at the left end on most systems, but even if that's how it should be read, it doesn't answer all the questions. Thankfully C99 clears it up, even if it does allow slightly less than C90 meant to.

Comment: @hvd: Due to the fact that representations for positive signed values have to match the representations for the corresponding unsigned values, I think the text on how `<<` affects unsigned values also defines the behavior for positive signed values that don't overflow. However, the range of the unsigned type need not be larger than the positive range of the corresponding signed type; the sign bit can be a padding bit in the unsigned type, and in that case, it would not need to be "above" the value bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll be getting an overflow when counting via `int i`, as `int` is 4 bytes wide here:

```
p[i << 20] = ...
```

Change

```
int i;
```

to be

```
size_t i;
```

`size_t` is the preferred type when addressing memory.

Answer (score 5):

An 32-bit `int` cannot store the value 2049 mb. You're invoking undefined behavior via signed integer overflow, and happen to be getting a negative number. On most 32-bit machines, when added to a pointer that wraps back around and ends up giving you the address you wanted, **by accident**. On 64-bit machines, that gives you an address roughly 2047 mb **below** the start of your block of memory (or wrapped around to the top of the 64-bit memory space).

Use the proper types. Here, `i` should have type `size_t`.